# Why Haskell's `fst` and `snd` have such a short (strange) names?

Tags: function, haskell, convention

I'm new to Haskell and what really bothers me at the moment is why the people who made the libraries added functions called `fst` and `snd` instead of using (normal) names like `first` and `second`. What's wrong with the latter names?

Personally I find these abbreviations ridiculous:
"Why `snd`? Why not `sec`, `scnd` or `scd`? Or why not `fir`, `frst`, `ft` or `frt`?"
It just lacks style. (But again - that's a personal opinion)

Comment: Why does POSIX have a function called `creat` instead of `create`?

Comment: I like how [basically the same question, applied to PHP instead of Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150637/why-are-the-built-in-functions-in-php-named-so-randomly), has 105 upvotes while this one is closed with negative votes only...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yup. That question was asked a _long_ time ago before SO got strict about debate, and wouldn't be tolerated today. VtC.

Comment: This question would be perfectly good and have an answer if it were edited to pose just the question it poses, rather than closed. It's clear that the use of `fst` and `snd` for projections has no Haskell-specific or even Miranda-specific explanation; see e.g. Scott "Data types as lattices" 1975, Milner "A theory of type polymorphism in programming" 1978 and later all over the place. Maybe something like p1 and p2 or π1 and π2 would be better?

Comment: If you made the names much longer, there'd be no use using them instead of just `\(a,_)->a` and `\(_,b)->b`, which is what `fst` and `snd` are defined as

Comment: I can't help myself but to think, that FST stands for FIST.

Comment: Some functional predecessors used the three-letter names `car` for the first element and `cdr` for the remaining, making `fst` and `snd` look pretty readable in comparison.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's clear the names were chosen to be 3 characters long whilst being as clear as possible as to the word - miss out all but the most prominent consonants. A lot of the standard functions have better/easier-to-follow names, but admittedly not all!

It's historical accident, really, what the names were, and there's not a lot we can do about it without annoying a lot of people who have got used to them and have a large code base relying on them. At least Haskell didn't call search grep!

Feel free to write `first = fst` and `second = snd` at the top of your file - it won't take long to use your preferred name, and `ghc -O2` will compile them out.

`first` and `second` are actually used for something more complicated in [Control.Arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:first) but you don't need to go that deep at this stage.

Comment: Just to note: `Control.Arrow` came *long* after Haskell98 standardized `fst` and `snd`.

Comment: @Rhymoid Definitely - I'm hinting at the caveat that you might want to use `first` and `second` for something more interesting later. I didn't give this as a reason for the short names `fst` and `snd`.

Comment: @Rhymoid btw I'd be very surprised if `fst` and `snd` were only introduced in 1998; I think they're original.

Comment: ML had `hd` and `tl` for the list destructors before Haskell existed, I think Haskell might have inherited `fst` and `snd` from Miranda.

Comment: They were inherited from Miranda, but Turner didn't make them up either.

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation but I'll give it a shot.   Both those are used in very specific cases.  They only access the first and second elements of a tuple that is only two elements.  They don't work for other sizes of tuples.  In many cases a programmer may have a type that has two elements but instead of using a tuple they will make their own class because it will be more descriptive.

Also, since they both are only used on a 2 element tuple it may frequently happen that you write `fst` when you mean `snd` and vice a versa.  Both these abbreviations are are 3 characters so when you go back and edit your source after you realize your mistake it won't change the format of your code or shift any characters in that line.  Not that important but still nice.

Opposed to object oriented languages a lot of code in haskell involves chaining together functions in one line is it kind of nice to have short functions so that it all fits in one line.  Many programmers use the 79 characters per line and there certainly is something appealing about not having to have a new line in one of your functions because it is too long.  Especially, a function that uses guards or pattern matching.

To show how terse haskell can be and still have good style.

```
sum []     = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Opposed to C++

```
template <T>
T sum(list<T> lst)
{
   T s = 0;
   for(list<T>::iterator it=lst.begin();it!=lst.end();++it)
      s += *it;

   return s;
}
```

But this is just a silly example.

I think it is a lot prettier than some object oriented code that has a 150 character line.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage with `snd` and `fst` is that they are equally long and code aligns nicely. Say

```
fun :: Bool -> (a, a) -> a
```

Now,

```
fun True  pair = fst pair
fun False pair = snd pair
```

Compared to

```
fun True  pair = first pair
fun False pair = second pair
```

The word `pair` is not aligned and I can't change them both simultaneously using visual mode in vim. It also bothers me visually.

Comment: Though your example isn't really consistent: you already padded `True` with an extra space to make the first `pair` column align; the same could be done with `first`. Also, if you eta-reduce this function the problem doesn't arise anymore.